# Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, compilation, visual-studio-2017

I want to know how to build a Unity project for **UWP**. (*Not to be* confused with a standalone application). I have to use Unity V **5.2.2f1**. The problem I am facing is an error message that I get when trying to build. It is

> Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

I tried various things online such as re-importing and moving the scripts to the Assets > Editor folder but so far no luck.

I want to mention that I am able to build this application for PC, Mac & Linux Standalone. It's just for the Windows Store (SDK : Universal 10) that I am getting this issue.
Also there are no scripts which are associated with Unity Editor.[(Please refer to this link for the error messages)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Jrv0.png)

The errors are as follows : 
Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors

Assets/Standard Assets/Camera Scripts/SmoothFollow.js(32,9): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'wantedRotationAngle'.

Assets/Standard Assets/Camera Scripts/SmoothFollow.js(33,9): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'wantedHeight'.

Assets/Standard Assets/Camera Scripts/SmoothFollow.js(35,9): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'currentRotationAngle'.

Assets/Standard Assets/Camera Scripts/SmoothFollow.js(42,9): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'currentHeight'.

Assets/Standard Assets/Camera Scripts/SmoothFollow.js(45,9): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'currentRotation'.

Assets/Standard Assets/Camera Scripts/SmoothFollow.js(50,31): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'currentRotation'.

Assets/Standard Assets/Camera Scripts/SmoothFollow.js(53,32): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'currentHeight'.

Assets/Standard Assets/Scripts/DragRigidbody.js(29,17): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'body'.

Assets/Standard Assets/Scripts/DragRigidbody.js(31,17): BCE0005: Unknown identifier: 'body'.

Comment: There should be additional error messages telling you exactly which scripts (and which lines) had compiler errors. Fix those and you will be able to build.

Comment: You didn't post the error. Usually, when there is a *"Error building Player because scripts had compiler errors"* error, it is followed by two other error messages with the actual error message. You should copy and post them in your question.

Comment: Look through your code and remove usings that have 'using Unity.Editor'. This prevents compilation

Comment: Thank-you for the prompt replies. I have updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: Select each error, copy and post them.

Comment: Alright done. Refer question.